# Avoiding nested loops but iterate over 2 values using (l)apply?

Tags: r, loops, apply

I'd like to get better at writing elegant code in R, and am trying to avoid writing nested loops, but cannot figure out an (l)apply solution to my problem.

I have a set of paired files, each of which has two variables associated with them - a name and a number. The filenames are long, so I'd like to generate a vector of filenames that can then be accessed by my own custom downstream function for reading them into a dataframe, plotting, etc.

For example, the files look like:

```
 5_simulationA.k  5_simulationA.b
10_simulationA.k 10_simulationA.b
 5_simulationB.k  5_simulationB.b
10_simulationB.k 10_simualtionB.b
```

The ".k" and ".b" files are mates of a pair and must stay together for downstream processing.

I could read in these files by writing a nested loop that would look something like,

```
K_files = c()
B_files = c()

for (i in c(A,B,C)){ # iterate over letter variable
    for (n in c(5,10,15)){ #iterate over numbers of the files
        k_filename = paste(n, "_simulation", i, ".k")
        b_filename = paste(n, "_simulation", i, ".b")
        K_files = c(K_files, k_filename)
        B_files = c(B_files, b_filename)
    }
}
```

This is of course very ugly and un-R-like. I would love to find a way to do this with the very powerful apply or lapply statements, or any other elegant solutions anyone might have. Thanks!

Comment: The function you are looking for is `mapply()` or alternativly `map2` from the `purrr` package (`purrr` simply makes the apply family a little more consistent).

Comment: Note that `c(A,B,C)` should be `c("A", "B", "C")`.

Comment: `Map(function(a,b) { a*b }, 1:3, 4:6)` (`Map` is a special case of `mapply`) is equivalent to `lapply(list(c(1,4), c(2,5), c(3,6)), function(z) { z[1]*z[2] })`. One advantage to `Map` is that it takes *1 or more* arguments, so this easily extends to *many* more arguments, as needed. (I personally find it much easier to read and troubleshoot than the `lapply` equivalent in this case. If you're curious, it is quite feasible to always use `Map` in place of `lapply`. I don't know if performance is significantly different ...)

Comment: mapply() solved the problem! Beautifully easy to implement, thanks! :)

Comment: Simple tests suggest that `lapply` is faster, but judgement on that debate should consider readability, maintainability, and the data structure.

Answer (score 3):

Base R function `outer` is meant for this kind of problem.

```
L <- c("A", "B", "C")
N <- c(5, 10, 15)

f <- function(i, n, e) paste0(n, "_simulation", i, e)
sapply(c(".k", ".b"), function(.e) outer(L, N, f, e = .e))
#     .k                 .b                
# [1,] "5_simulationA.k"  "5_simulationA.b" 
# [2,] "5_simulationB.k"  "5_simulationB.b" 
# [3,] "5_simulationC.k"  "5_simulationC.b" 
# [4,] "10_simulationA.k" "10_simulationA.b"
# [5,] "10_simulationB.k" "10_simulationB.b"
# [6,] "10_simulationC.k" "10_simulationC.b"
# [7,] "15_simulationA.k" "15_simulationA.b"
# [8,] "15_simulationB.k" "15_simulationB.b"
# [9,] "15_simulationC.k" "15_simulationC.b"
```

Answer (score 2):

From OP's example output filenames, it looks like we want all combinations of `n` and `i`. `expand.grid` returns a dataframe of all combinations of `n`s and `i`s. We could then use `apply` to loop through its row to generate the filenames:

```
i <- c("A", "B", "C")
n <- c(5, 10, 15)
combi <- expand.grid(n = n, i = i)

invisible(apply(combi, 1, function(x){
  k_filename = paste0(x[1], "_simulation", x[2], ".k")
  b_filename = paste0(x[1], "_simulation", x[2], ".b")
  print(k_filename)
  print(b_filename)
}))
```

Noticed that I used `invisible` to suppress the output of `apply` since we are only interested in the side-effects (read/write files). Alternatively, we can use `pwalk` from `purrr`, which takes each column of the same `expand.grid` dataframe as input and creates the filenames silently:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
combi %>%
  pwalk(~ {
    k_filename = paste0(.x, "_simulation", .y, ".k")
    b_filename = paste0(.x, "_simulation", .y, ".b")
    print(k_filename)
    print(b_filename)
  })
```

**Output:**

```
[1] "5_simulationA.k"
[1] "5_simulationA.b"
[1] "10_simulationA.k"
[1] "10_simulationA.b"
[1] "15_simulationA.k"
[1] "15_simulationA.b"
[1] "5_simulationB.k"
[1] "5_simulationB.b"
[1] "10_simulationB.k"
[1] "10_simulationB.b"
[1] "15_simulationB.k"
[1] "15_simulationB.b"
[1] "5_simulationC.k"
[1] "5_simulationC.b"
[1] "10_simulationC.k"
[1] "10_simulationC.b"
[1] "15_simulationC.k"
[1] "15_simulationC.b"
```

Comment: A bit more efficient I guess: `y <- c("A", "B", "C"); x <- c(5, 10, 15); z <- c("k", "b"); f <- function(x, y, z) sprintf(fmt = "%d_simulation%s.%s", x, y, z); do.call(f, expand.grid(x = x, y = y, z = z))`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
Type = c("A", "B", "C")
Index = c(5, 10, 15)

crossing(Type, Index) %>% 
mutate(k_filename = map2_chr(Index, Type, ~paste(.x, "_simulation", .y, ".k", sep="")), 
       b_filename = map2_chr(Index, Type, ~paste(.x, "_simulation", .y, ".b", sep=""))) -> names
```

After that, you can access the `k_filename` or `b_filename` using `pull`

```
K_files <- names %>% pull(k_filename)
```